# Form doesn't submit all fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a pretty huge form which I am able to extend **dynamically with JavaScript**. In this form I am having different **DataSets with about 50 fields** to submit each. When I submit the form I am running through a for loop **from 0 to 100** to check which fields are set. So I create the HTML like this:

```
<form id = "formUpdate" role="form" action="index.php?action=update" method="post">
    <table id="table" class="table table-hover"><thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Head1
            <th> Head2
            <th> Head3
            <th> Head4
            <th> Head5
            <th> Head6
            <th> ...
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        for ($i=0;$i<$dataSets;$i++){  ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><label><?php echo $test[$i]['1']; ?> </label></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <input required class="form-control formsUser" form="formUpdate" name="fieldA<?php echo $test[$i]['2']; ?>" value=""></input>
                                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <textarea style="height:34px" class="form-control formsUser" form="formUpdate" name="fieldB<?php echo $test[$i]['3'];?>" required></textarea>
                                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <input class="form-control formsUser" form="formUpdate" name="fieldC<?php echo $test[$i]['4']; ?>" required value=""></input>
                                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <input class="form-control formsUser" form="formUpdate" name="fieldD<?php echo $test[$i]['5']; ?>" required value=""></input>
                                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <input class="form-control formsUser" form="formUpdate" name="fieldE<?php echo $test[$i]['6']; ?>" value=""></input>
                            </tr>
                   <?php } ?>
   </table>
   <button class="btn btn-success" form="formUpdate" type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
public function update(){
     print_r($_REQUEST);
     for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
          $string = "fieldA".$i;

          if (isset($_POST[$string])){
              // set the other _POSTS
          }
          else {
              //do something different
          }
      }
}
```

But this works only for the **first 10 Datasets**. When I call `print_r($_REQUEST);` it also just contains the content of the fields of the first 10 Datasets. I read about the limit of `max_input_vars` in the **php.ini** and increased this value, but nothing has changed. Besides I shouldn't reach the default value of 1,000 with my data. I also tried changing the value of `max_input_nesting_level`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size`.

Comment: need some more codes  this is not enough

Comment: @Aniket i think he post sample code without <form> tag. otherwise few data can not inserted right?

Comment: Added some more HTML. Sorry that I didn't post the <form>-Tag.

Comment: OMG. Got the Problem. I am using DataTables and when submitting the form, the table is redrawed showing the first 10 Datasets only...sorry for that guys and thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Manu1038 post this comment as an answer so we know your question is answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

OMG. Got the Problem. I am using DataTables and when submitting the form, the table is redrawed showing the first 10 Datasets only...sorry for that guys and thanks for your help :)